# is there any method to remove such watermark?

Tags: flash

I want to finish my flash, but only need a banner. I download a flash banner maker from Sothink SWF Easy, the site is http://www.sothink.com/product/swfeasy/ , which is free trial version, I like its templetes very much , but there is a watermark “easy flash banner maker” at the back of my flash banner. Who once used this tool? is there any method to remove such watermark? Please help.

Comment: Buy the software? Anything else would probably be violating the terms of the license and hence illegal.

Answer (score 1):

It appears they want you to buy the full version for US$50 then there will be no banner.